# notation in abstract algebra: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

What does $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ mean? Is it $\{ a+b\sqrt{2}  \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ ?

Comment: My humble opinion: yes.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/720375/242) for ring and field adjunctions.

Comment: Yes, but be careful, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})\neq\{a+b\sqrt[3]{2} \mid a,b\in \Bbb Q \}$.

Comment: hmm, so what is that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Formally, $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ means “the smallest field containing $a$ and $\mathbb{Q}$". It turns out that the smallest field containing both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ is precisely the field you wrote.

Comment: Good answer!! Why not $\sqrt1$ or $\sqrt0$?

Comment: @manooooh what about them?

Comment: Why they are not "The smallest field"? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @manooooh Do you know what a field is?

Comment: Good answer by the way. It is important to note that the definition is what you wrote in the answer. For example $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is not $\{a+b\pi: a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. It's the specific element $\sqrt{2}$ for which $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ can be described in such a simple way.

Comment: I learnt that a field is a function $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$.