# Field Extension Question for Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I cannot seem to find the answer to this question on the internet. It is a question about field extensions for an element $a,b \neq F$ but in some extension $K$.

I am wondering if $F(a,b)= \lbrace p(a,b) : p(x,y) \in \mathbb[x,y] \rbrace$. It seems like it should be the case since $F(a)= \lbrace p(a) : p(x) \in F[x] \rbrace$. Also, out of curiosity, is $F(a,b)=F(a) \cup F(b) $?

Also, if neither of these are the case, a helpful example or explanation would awesome. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your first hunch.  If we have fields $F \subset K$ and an element $a \in K$, then by definition, $F(a)$ is defined to be the smallest subfield of $K$ that contains $a$.  However, if $a$ is algebraic over $F$, then $F(a) = \{p(a) \ | \ p(x) \in F[x] \}$.  For a proof that these are equivalent statements when $a$ is algebraic, see my post [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080336/adjoining-a-number-to-a-field/1080337#1080337).

Following the above, provided $a$ and $b$ are algebraic over $F$, we have $F(a, b) = F(a)(b) = \{p(b) \ | \ p(x) \in F(a)[x] \}$, and when you think about it, this is equal to the set $\{p(a, b) \ | \ p(x, y) \in F[x, y] \}$.

However, it is *not* true that $F(a, b) = F(a) \cup F(b)$.  To see this, let $F = \mathbb{Q}$, and let $a = \sqrt{2}$ and $b = \sqrt{3}$.  Then $\sqrt{6} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$, but $\sqrt{6} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and likewise $\sqrt{6} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$.  Therefore, it cannot be the case that $\sqrt{6} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \cup \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Kaj is good. But I'll add one thing: This only works if $a,b$ are algebraic over $F$. Same goes for $F(a)=\{p(a):p(x)\in F[x]\}$

Comment: Oh you are correct indeed.  Thanks for pointing out my omission!