# Given two fields, constructing a field containing both

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In the text by Dummit and Foote, the authors introduce the idea of an algebraic closure, and also prove that one always exists for every field $F$.  They then comment that we can "...speak sensibly of the composite of any collection of algebraic extensions by viewing them as subfields of an algebraic closure."

But I'm a bit confused by this.  Suppose we have two fields $K_1$ and $K_2$.  Then we have the two algebraic closures $\overline{K_1}$ and $\overline{K_2}$, but it doesn't necessarily follow that either one of these algebraic closures contains both $K_1$ and $K_2$...

So I have two questions:

1. How do we construct the big field that contains both $K_1$ and $K_2$?
2. The quoted comment said that $K_1$ and $K_2$ must be algebraic extensions...why is this?

Comment: I don't know much field theory, but don't you need more conditions on $K_1,K_2$?  Choose $K_1 = \mathbb F_2$, and $K_2 = \mathbb Q$.  How can you have a mutual extension of them?

Comment: If you know about tensor products then, for a field $F$ contained in both $K_1$ and $K_2$, the ring $K_1 \otimes_F K_2$ leads to a construction you seek: pick a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ in this ring (an $F$-algebra) and the composite $K_1 \rightarrow (K_1 \otimes_F K_2)/\mathfrak m$ where $x \mapsto x \otimes 1 \bmod \mathfrak m$ is a ring homomorphism of fields and hence injective, and likewise for $K_2 \rightarrow (K_1 \otimes_F K_2)/\mathfrak m$ by $y \mapsto 1 \otimes y \bmod \mathfrak m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought, I don't think my question is too complicated.  The first thing to note (as was pointed out in the comments section and by Kaj Hansen) is that the fields $K_1$ and $K_2$ must both be extensions of the same base field $F$.

Now to answer the two questions I originally asked:

1. *How do we construct the big field that contains both $K_1$ and $K_2$?*

Since $K_1 / F$ is algebraic over $F$, we must have $K_1 \subseteq \overline{F}$, where $\overline{F}$ is one choice of algebraic closure for $F$ (there are many choices, but they are all isomorphic).  If we stick with this same choice of algebraic closure, then $K_2 \subseteq \overline{F}$.  So $\overline{F}$ is the "big field".

2. *The quoted comment said that $K_1$ and $K_2$ must be algebraic extensions...why is this?*

I think it is still possible to construct a big field extension of $F$ containing $K_1$ and $K_2$ if $K_1$ and $K_2$ are not both algebraic over $F$.  But it is more straightforward if $K_1$ and $K_2$ are algebraic over $F$, since we can use $\overline{F}$ as our big field.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing to note here is that $K_1$ and $K_2$ must be algebraic extensions of *the same base field*.  There's no way we can find a field $L$ such that both $\mathbb{F}_9$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ are subfields of $L$.

So let's assume that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are both algebraic extensions of some base field $F$.  The general idea here is that $K_1 = F(S_1)$ and $K_2 = F(S_2)$, where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are (possibly countably infinite) collections of roots of polynomials in $F[x]$.  Because the algebraic closure of $F$ is constructed by adjoining *all* the roots of every possible polynomial in $F[x]$ to $F$, we must have $F(S_1) \subset \overline{F}$, and likewise for $F(S_2)$.  In many cases, we do not have to go all the way to the algebraic closure; notice that both $F(S_1)$ and $F(S_2)$ will be contained in $F(S_1 \cup S_2)$.  For a concrete example, $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{3})$ are both contained in $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$.

Technically, it seems that one can find a larger field containing both $K_1$ and $K_2$ as long as these fields have the same characteristic -- i.e. both have $\mathbb{Q}$ or both have $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (for the same $p$) as a subfield.  Even if $K_1$ and $K_2$ are not strictly algebraic extensions, they will nevertheless be generated by (i.e. have a basis of) some collection of algebraic elements together with some collection of transcendental elements.  One can find a field containing both $K_1$ and $K_2$ by considering the field generated by the union of all of the algebraic / transcendental generators for both fields.

---

Recall that we can think of extensions of a field $F$ as a vector space over $F$.  Because of this, we are able to make analogies with vector spaces we're comfier working with to help grasp the concept:

Suppose we have two vector spaces $S_1$ and $S_2$, which are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{10}$.  Let's denote the "standard basis vectors" as $\mathbf{e}_k$, which have all zeros except for a $1$ in the $k^\text{th}$ slot.  Let $S_1$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{10}$ with the basis $\mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_5, \text{ and } \mathbf{e}_9$, and let $S_2$ be the subspace with basis $\mathbf{e}_2$ and $\mathbf{e}_3$.  That is to say:

$$S_1 = \text{Span} \Big( \mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_5, \mathbf{e}_9 \Big)$$
$$S_2 = \text{Span} \Big( \mathbf{e}_2, \mathbf{e}_3 \Big)$$

One can ask: "What is the smallest subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{10}$ that contains both $S_1$ and $S_2$?".  It isn't too hard to convince ourselves that the answer will be the subspace spanned by $\mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2, \mathbf{e}_3, \mathbf{e}_5, \text{ and } \mathbf{e}_9$.  In other words, the subspace requested has as its basis elements the union of the basis elements from the two original subspaces $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Comment: thanks for this answer. Two questions: (1) If $K_1$ is an algebraic extension, how do you know there exists a set $S_1$ of roots with $K_1 = F(S_1)$?  If this is some fundamental result that I am just not aware of, I apologize. And (2) What is your definition of $F(S_1)$?  I would like to say it is the smallest subfield of _____ containing $F$ and $S_1$, but the whole point of this discussion seems to be about finding ______...?

Comment: @SamY., to answer your first question, the definition of an algebraic extension is that every element is a root of a polynomial in $F[x]$ (with elements of $F$ being roots of linear polynomials).  We can simply start choosing elements in $K_1 \setminus F$ to adjoin to $F$ so as to create a tower $F \subset F(a_1) \subset F(a_1, a_2) \subset \cdots \subset F(S_1) = K_1$.  There are two ways to think of the notation $F(a)$, and one can show that they are equivalent.  First, $F(a)$ can be thought of as the smallest field containing both the element $a$ and $F$ as a subfield.

Comment: Second, $F(a) = \{ f(a) \ | \ f(x) \in F[x] \}$ - i.e. the set of all polynomial evaluations at $a$.  Sorry if it feels like I'm rambling, but I think this is all potentially relevant to get a good feel for what's going on.  You can read further discussion I have on this point here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080336/adjoining-a-number-to-a-field/1080337#1080337

Comment: And with that, it seems I have answered your second question: $F(S_1)$ can indeed be thought of as the smallest subfield of the algebraic closure of $F$ containing both $F$ and $S_1$.  This is sort of going back to the above point: it can also be thought of in terms of a set of polynomial evaluations.  What's more, there is a set $T \supseteq S_1$ such that $F(T)$ is the algebraic closure of $F$.  It seems to me the whole point of this discussion is, given two algebraic extensions $K_1$, $K_2$ of $F$, to construct an extension $K \subseteq \overline{F}$ such that $K$ contains both $K_1$ and

Comment: $K_2$.  The best way of seeing this construction is in terms of a "basis" for the extension (in the sense that every extension of $F$ can be thought of as a vector space over $F$).  The "basis" for the field you want to construct is simply the union of the two bases for the original extensions $K_1$ and $K_2$.  It's all about spanning sets.  At any rate, I think the above link might be key to understanding the idea I'm struggling to convey here: indeed, we can think of $F(S_1)$ as "the smallest field containing $S_1$ and $F$", but that's not being satisfactorily descriptive unless we think

Comment: instead in terms of $F(S_1)$ as being a set of evaluations of polynomials.  In particular, the elements of $F(S_1)$ look like $g(a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n)$, where $g$ can be a polynomial in $n$ indeterminants with coefficients in $F$ for *any* $n \leq |S_1|$ and the $a_k$'s elements of $S_1$.  Again, major sorry for the rambling.  I'll be happy to clear anything up, and hopefully I didn't just spawn more confusion than we started with.

Comment: Thank you so much for all these comments and the answer!  They are very helpful.  I think I have figured out a separate solution (see my answer) that is perhaps a little easier for me to understand...