# What is $\mathbb{Z}[a]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

Let $\alpha$ be algebraic over a field $F$. Then, $F(\alpha)$ denotes the subfield of $F$ generated by $\alpha$. This is the standard definition of $F(\alpha)$.

Under this definition, for example, one can **prove** that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})=\{a+b\sqrt{D}:a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ for some square free integer $D$.

Like the above example, is there a general way to define $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ for suitable arbitrary $a\in \mathbb{Z}$?

To be specific, in basic algebra texts, rings such as $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ are defined as span of $1$ and $x$. So that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is **defined as** $\{a+ib:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. However, I don't like this definition and curious to know whether there is a general definition which chooses suitable arbitrary $a$'s and form $\mathbb{Z}[a]$.

Also, I'm curious why people use the bracket $[a]$ for $\mathbb{Z}$ while people use $(a)$ for $\mathbb{Q}$. (Why $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}(a)$ just like $\mathbb{Q}(a)$?)

Comment: It's a [ring adjunction.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/15463/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a subring of a (let's say) commutative ring with unit $A$. The intersection of subrings of $A$ containing a given subset $S$ of $A$ is again a subring of $A$ containing $S$, so that the notion of smallest subring of $A$ containing $S$ makes sense : just take the intersection of all such subrings. This smallest subring is called the subring of $A$ containing $S$. You can easily show that it is equal to the set $$\{P(s_1,\ldots,s_n)\;|\;n\in\mathbf{N}, s_1,\ldots,s_n\in S, P\in \mathbf{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\}.$$
Now if $S = R\cup T$ for a subset $T$ of $A$, this ring is noted $R[T]$ and is in fact equal to $$\{P(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\;|\;n\in\mathbf{N}, t_1,\ldots,t_n\in T, P\in R[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\}$$ and is in fact equal to the smallest sub-$R$-algebra of $A$ containing $T$. Finally, if $T = \{\alpha\}$ for an $\alpha\in A$, one notes $R[T] = R[\alpha]$, and this is equal to $$\{P(\alpha)\;|\;P\in R[x]\}.$$

Why the brackets or the parenthesis ? The notation comes from the formal variable case notation : for instance $k[T]$ for the polynomials in $T$ with coefficient in $k$ and $k(T)$ for the rational functions with coefficients in $k$ in the variable $T$. Imagine $R = \mathbf{Q}$, $A = \mathbf{R}$, and $\alpha\in A$. If $\alpha$ is a root of a non-zero from $\mathbf{Q}[T]$, then you have in fact that $\mathbf{Q}[\alpha] = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ where the latter is the smallest sub-field of $\mathbf{R}$ containing $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\alpha$. But if it is not, that is, if $\alpha$ is transcendent over $\mathbf{Q}$, then $\mathbf{Q}[\alpha] \not= \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$, and then you have an isomorphism $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha) \simeq \mathbf{Q}(T)$ inducing an isomoprhism $\mathbf{Q}[\alpha] \simeq \mathbf{Q}[T]$.

Comment: I don't get the first paragraph. Yes, I know it's possible to form the smallest ring containing $S$. But what do you mean this smallest one is equal to the set you wrote? (Evaluation of n-variable polynomials in $T$) what is $A$?

Comment: $A$ is, as stated, a ring containg $R$. When you look at $R[\textrm{something}]$, all your rings always have to "live" in a bigger "ambient" ring, which I choose to be $A$. When I say that the smallest ring bla bla bla is equal to the set, I mean that these to sets are equal, that there are the same. To check this equality, you can check that the set in question is a ring, and that it is contained in any ring containg $S$.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. So to be very specific, is it okay to write $R_A[T]$ rather than $R[T]$?

Comment: Yes, indeed. But you can drop the index $A$ when you work with a fixed $A$.

Answer (score 2):

The definition with "span" is, at best, confusing (unless some things were explicitly agreed on a priori), and wrong at worst. By definition

$$R[\alpha]:=\left\{f(\alpha)\;:\;\;f(x)\in R[x]\right\}$$

when $\;R\;$ is any ring (commutative with unit, to make things nicer)

The brackets usually denote ring, while the round parentheses *always* (in the standard use) denote field of rational functions.

It is an easy and nice lemma to prove that, for example with $\;\Bbb Q\;$ and some $\;\alpha\in\Bbb C\;$ , we have that $\;\Bbb Q[\alpha]=\Bbb Q(\alpha)\iff \alpha\;$ is *algebraic* . Of course, we *always* have $\;\Bbb Q[\alpha]\subset\Bbb Q(\alpha)\;$

Comment: This seems a nice definition, but is it standard? Is it okay to write $R[\alpha]$ to mean the ring without an explanation?

Comment: @Rubertos As far as I am aware, it is completely standard and international.

Comment: Moreover, is there a name for $R[\alpha]$? (I want to read "things" about this in wikipeida or something like that..) and thank you so much!

Comment: $\;R[\alpha]\;$ can be either called "the ring of values at $\;\alpha\;$  of polynomials in $\;R\;$", or "the ring generated by $\;R\,,\,and\;\;\alpha\;$ , etc.

Comment: The most standard names being "the (sub-)ring generated by $\alpha$ and $R$", or "the (sub-)$R$-algebra generated by $\alpha$".

Comment: "The subring"...of what or who?