# what is $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I have an exercise that uses the ring  $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$. I guess are integers but what $\frac{1}{2}$ means?

Comment: Adjoint ring of the ring of integers, $1/2$ is one-half.

Comment: Is denotes a [ring adjunction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/15463/242).

Answer (score 3):

It's the ring of the numbers of the form $\frac n{2^m}$, with $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $m\in\mathbb Z^+$. More generally, if $\alpha\in\mathbb C$, then $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ is the ring of the numbers of the form $a_0+a_1\alpha+\cdots+a_n\alpha^n$, with $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I believe $\{{n\over 2}\}$ does not form a ring, since it doesn't contain ${1\over 2}\cdot{1\over 2}={1\over 4}$.

Comment: Of course! I've edited my answer. Thank you.